# Rails - SSL error with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've used Devise before with little trouble. The only things I can think of that are different for this project is that I'm trying omniauth (I've only added the gems - no functionality yet) for the first time and I've switched from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to sign up a new user with Devise I get the error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol

Extracted source (around line #586):


584    logging "TLS connection started"
585    s.sync_close = true
586    s.connect
587    if @ssl_context.verify_mode != OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
588        s.post_connection_check(@address)
589    end
```

In config/environments/development.rb I have:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :tls => true,
    :domain => 'gmail.com', #you can also use google.com
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => 'my_email@gmail.com',
    :password => 'password'
  }
```

I really don't understand this problem so any help at all will be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove your email and passwords.

Comment: @bekicot I did that and restarted my server but I'm getting the same error

Comment: I mean you just tell the world your email address and password.

Comment: Oh! Oops okay, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the SSL_Cert_file environmental variable to:

edit the ~/.bashrc file and add:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

If that doesn't work and you are using RVM maybe setting the path to: `~/.rvm/usr/ssl/cert.pem`

Before you make any changes just note down what the path currently is so that you can set it back if needed.

Comment: Okay, forgive me for sounding ignorant but where do I set this variable? In config/environments/development.rb? Because the line that the error points to is part of Devise and not my actual code.

Comment: I've uptadted my post.

Comment: I've just started my rails server for the first time today and everything seems to be working fine. I haven't even changed anything from yesterday (apart from the email account I was using). So, do you recommend adding that line to ~/.bash.rc anyway or should I just wait and try it if/when the error crops up again? -- Oh! wait I know what I changed! Hang on....

Comment: Okay so I've recreated the error and adding that line to ~./bashrc with no luck. I used RVM to install ruby but other than that I haven't really touched it. Where to I set that path/find out what the current path is? I tried to google this but I'm afraid of messing something up.

Comment: After adding the environment variable must restart the pc

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted my computer and I'm still getting that error.